# Find and insert dummy rows - possible scenario for OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a mock up of the situation we've got:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#People') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #People END;
CREATE TABLE #People
    (
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Category VARCHAR(20),
    ID INT
    );
INSERT INTO #People
    values
    ('x','Bronze',1),
    ('y','Bronze',2),
    ('z','Silver',3),
    ('j','Gold',4),
    ('q','Bronze',5),
    ('x','Silver',1);


IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Category') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Category END;
CREATE TABLE #Category
    (
    Category VARCHAR(100)
    );
INSERT INTO #Category
    values
    ('Gold'),
    ('Silver'),
    ('Bronze');
```

If a `name` does not have a `Category` e.g. `x` does not have `Gold` then I'd like a row creating and adding into the table `#People` with an `ID` of -1.

Current solution I have is this:

```
WITH x AS
    (
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            x.Name,
            s.Category
    FROM    #People x
            CROSS JOIN #Category s
    )
INSERT  INTO    #People
SELECT  J.Name,
        J.Category,
        ID = -1
FROM    x J
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    #People Q
        WHERE   J.Name = Q.Name
                AND J.Category = Q.Category
        );
```

See it works!...:

```
SELECT *
FROM #People;
```

I have a feeling `CROSS APPLY` might be a good operator to use in order to simplify the above - What is the simplest way to find, create and insert these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into People(Name, Category, Id)
(
select distinct
  p.Name, 
  c.Category, 
  p.Id 
from 
        people p 
  cross join category c
where
  Concat(p.id, c.Category) not in (select Concat(id, Category) from people)
);
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92cd5/14

Comment: +1 thanks Hugh - it works although I suspect there's a shorter answer out there!

Comment: @whytheq - I am not so sure about that, but in any case my solution is not radically different from yours